# Manually adding package dependencies in eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, package

In eclipse IDE, Quick assistant aids to import package package dependency automatically.
However, sometimes it takes to much time to click all the errors to import the dependent packages.

How can I do that manually? I mean, what configuration file Quick Assistant modify to add the dependency?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your save actions to organize imports.

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-save-actions.htm

Answer (score 1):

The action you want is "Organize Imports" which is also accessible using the keystroke: Ctrl+Shift+o

Answer (score 0):

I found that `Import-Package` in `MANIFEST.MF` is the one eclipse automatically adds the dependency files.

[image]